# Do you mind related question

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Do you mind if I join you?

and Do you mind if I join with you?

Which one is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you meet some friends and want to go with them, the usual thing to say might be:

> Do you mind if I join you?

The "with" is implied but informally it is usually left out.

You could say:

> Do you mind if I join *with* you?

but this sounds incredibly formal (the joining part). It might be OK if you were asking your girlfriend to marry you.

Comment: Maybe, they have a bit different meaning. "join you" implies that you could be the host for the event. well, "join with you" is probably implying you and he/she together join an event. But i'm not sure if I'm correct. it's just my conjecture.

Comment: Suppose, you have two options. which one do you pick, @user3169?

Comment: @orbit Can you add the situation where you are using the phrase to your question? In general, the first one should usually be OK.

Comment: @dan I think that would be "Do you mind if **we** join you?"

Comment: @user3169 thanks for convenience, I gave an exam. question is, which one is correct? a) Do you mind if I join you? b) Do you mind if I join with you?